# Нужны ли знаки препинания после "Мало ли"?

Tags: пунктуация

Хорошо, что он в чехле был, так что вряд ли повредился. Но мало ли кто-то успеет забрать…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно так:

*Хорошо, что он в чехле был, так что вряд ли повредился. Но **мало ли кто** успеет (может) забрать…*

**Пояснение**

1. **[Русский орфографический словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B8):**

**мало ли кто** (что, какой, где, куда, когда)

2. **[Словарь-справочник по пунктуации](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/378/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE___%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5___%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%E2%80%A6)**

**мало ли что / где / какой…**

Цельное по смыслу выражение.
Между частями выражения (перед словом «что») знак препинания не ставится.

3. **[Карта слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE+%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE)**

*Теперь, когда они уходили, всегда закрывали форточку – **мало ли кто** может залезть.*